# How to call videojs object from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, video.js

In my main html file (index.html), I have imported the videojs javascript file in the header.
In the body I've set the videojs player ready.

What i want is using the videojs player object from another javascript file e.g. set playrate, .

But when I code it, and i want to show the id, it's said undefined and i got a script error.

I'm working in visual studio 2019

Hopefully that anyone have some clues for me.

Best Regards
Klaasjan

The error i got is :
The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)

Comment: show your code
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Two cases:

1. Video Js Object hasn't initialized before you set PlayRate. in this
   case, you should move import your script after body tag
2. You only want to use Video Js Object, you can use global valuable.

in index.html

```
window['videojsPlayer'] = new videojsPlayer();
```

in another file.

```
window['videojsPlayer'].setPlayrate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CadenceVR.com BTLE example</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="../favicon.png">
    <script>window.HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS = false;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="heartRateSensor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cyclingSpeedCadence.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="statusText">Heart   : 0 BPM &#x2764;</div>
        <div id="SpeedText">Speed   :  0,0 KM/H</div>
        <div id="CadenceText">Cadence :  0 RPM</div>
        <label for="name">Speedrate between 1 and 4:</label>
        <input type="text" id="speedrate" name="speedrate" required minlength="1" maxlength="1" size="2">
        <button type="button" name="BTLEbutton1" value="BTLEClick1" onclick="onButtonClickSetVideoRate();">Set Video speed rate</button>
        <button type="button" name="BTLEbutton2" value="BTLEClick2" onclick="onButtonClickHart();">Discover Heart Devices</button>
        <button type="button" name="BTLEbutton3" value="BTLEClick3" onclick="onButtonClickCSC();">Discover S_C Devices</button>
    </div>

   

    <video id='cvrvideo' class='video-js' controls preload="auto"
           poster='My-jpg' height="320" width="640" data-setup='{}'>
        <source src='My-mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        <p class='vjs-no-js'>
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
    </video>

    <script>
         videojs('cvrvideo').ready(function(){
           
             // Store the video object
             var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
             // Make up an aspect ratio
             var aspectRatio = 264/640; 

             function resizeVideoJS(){
                 var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
                 myPlayer.width(width);
                 myPlayer.height(width * aspectRatio);
             }
      
             // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
             resizeVideoJS();
             // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
             window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; 
         });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And in my core.js file i have the following code : 

// Store the video object
var myPlayer = videojs('cvrvideo'), id = myPlayer.id();